# Weird HTML Row Wrapping

Tags: javascript, css

I am building an dynamically created gallery, where ajax/php fetch some images and then load those images into a dynamically created table. I have a set width for this table and I want the overflow only in the x direction. The issue is that the table row (tr) seems to wrap itself. I have tried using the css overflow-x property, I have tried manipulating the table width (which is inside a div), and I have tried using css to turn off wrapping. None of this helps and the table scrolls vertically instead of horizontally. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the table structure:

```
    <table><tr><td><img style="width:100px;"/></td>...(many more columns)...</tr></table>
```

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, please consider marking it as the answer. The same would apply to your other questions, by the way. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `<div>`s.

Try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="gallery-wrapper">
    <div><img src="..." /></div>
    ...
    <div><img src="..." /></div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
div#gallery-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div#gallery-wrapper > div{
   display:inline-block;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
```

P.S. There are actually many other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of using a table in the wrong context and why it's not recommended. If you absolutely must use the table layout then put the image in a div inside the td and set the divs overflow.

```
  <table><tr><td><div class="imageDiv"><img style="width:100px;"/></div></td>...(many more columns)...</tr></table>

.imageDiv{overflow-x:scroll;}
```

Comment: This would make the individual images scrollable, but I suppose the question is around having the whole gallery scrollable.

Comment: I read it as individual images, not 100% sure. If you're right your answer is the right one. At least he can choose what he's actually after.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the jscrollpane that is jquery plugin.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and overflow not for the table, but for a div around the table, so that the table can be scrolled inside this div:

```
<div style="width:1000px; overflow-x:scroll;"><table>...</table></div>
```